# Rolling a dice in swift using a while function and printing results until the result is 1

Tags: swift, random, while-loop

I'm really new to Swift and I have a task asking me to create a while loop that simulates rolling a 6-sided dice repeatedly until a 1 is rolled. After each roll, print the value.

In just about every iteration I've tried over the last 2 hours I keep ending in an infinite loop that explodes Xcode.

Any help would be fantastic!

```swift
var dieRoll = Int.random(in: 1...6)

while dieRoll <= 6 {
    print (dieRoll)
    if dieRoll == 1 {
        print ("You win!")
    }
}
```

Got it to this point, it no longer runs endlessly but it acts weird and returns values of 1 without printing "You win!"

```swift
func dieRoll(x: Int) -> Int {
    return Int.random(in:1...6)
}

while dieRoll(x: 0) > 1 {
    print(dieRoll(x: 0))
    if dieRoll(x: 1) == 1 {
        print("You win!")
    }
    else {
        RETURN
    }
}
```

Comment: hint: You never re-roll the dice, you just roll it once with the random, then get stuck in the while loop. Plus you need a `return` or `break` statement if you want to get out of the loop when it is equal to 1

Comment: Okay, the module I was working on didn't have any information about doing return or break but the next module does. I'm gonna carry on with the next lessons and see if I can come back to this. Thanks!

Comment: I think the point is to print in console how many rolls it takes to get a random return of 1. Like say for instance you wanted to model how many rolls on average it takes out of 10 runs to get a result of 1. It's still messing me up but I think I've gotten closer to figuring it out. It's not endlessly rolling anymore but It needs work still.

Answer (score 0):

Your dieRoll variable is declared AS A VARIABLE yet you never change it! Try “rerolling” within the While Loop

Also, there’s always the chance that a 6 never gets rolled... idk if you want to mess with “real” probabilities but if you’re finding issues you may want to institute a “max number of rolls”... personally I wouldn’t but hey you never know

TDLR: last line of the while-loop should reroll your dieRoll var

Comment: Thanks! The rerolling got me to thinking how to change a variable from within a loop and after about 30 tries I finally got something that works. 

The "max number of rolls" is the break when it eventually rolls a 1. Once it hits the 1 the loop should end and print out every roll before that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I got away from the string text and focused on what the code was saying versus what my typing was saying. Ended up with this (probably a monstrosity to you experienced folks) but it looks something like this.

```swift
var rolling = Int.random(in: 1...6)

while rolling > 1 {
    print(rolling)
    if rolling == 1 {
        break
    } else {
        rolling = Int.random(in: 1...6)
    }
}
print(rolling)
```

And every time I run it it ends on a 1 so it does what it needs to!